# Document repetitiveness algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a collection of documents which have been written at 2 different time period. There is an inkling that the document written in period 1 is more concise than documents in period 2. They are all on the same subject.

The only thing I have been able to come up with is using a LZW algorithm and taking the ratio of the compressed/original to calculate a sort of conciseness of the document.

I would like the results to be :

1. Document 1 - Repetitiveness index or percentage = 25% or similar metric. After that, I'll create a dataframe of documents in different period with the repetitiveness index and do statistical tests to see the statistical significance.

Comment: What *exactly* is your *coding* question?

Comment: Hi desertnaut, thanks for the response. More than a coding questions, it's an algorithm question. What is the sort of algorithm or methods I can apply to this to get the results I need? Thanks a lot!